# Google search question, front page not showing

Tags: google, pagerank

I know this is probably a dumb question but I hope someone can give me some insight;

I was ranked on Google first page of search results for "funny st patricks day shirts" but I was third from the bottom and not familiar enough with SEO, so I signed up for "Attracta" to rank higher. Big mistake.

Since using Attracta, I've lost the first page and I'm now on the fourth page in that search. What I noticed is that Google is now just showing a sub-page or side page, (a link from my front page, to a page which has only a few designs in it) this is not where I would want customers to land first... but my front page is not showing in that search anymore. Obviously, the title of this side page is not geared toward that search result, so I know that's why I have the pr drop.

Why is my front page not ranking over that page, though? Why is it apparently gone from that search, or so far back no one will ever find it?

I need to know how to fix this quick if anyone has any advice at all for me. It's the busiest season for my website and the people who were stealing design ideas from me are all ranked higher than my site now. (I can prove this, lol) So, I'm very frustrated by that.

I would be very grateful to have any advice at all as to what I can do to fix this.

THANKS in advance for any advice you can offer.

Catelyn

Comment: I had to remove your URL from your question or else this would have to be closed as too localized. But I think you've given enough information for people to help you with this without it.

Comment: Opps, thank you!  I did just now get a response from Attracta and they say I have Meta Tag issues. They are duplicated? I don't know where to fix this, but I'm searching...

Comment: What changes were made by Attracta to the home page? What did they do for you as a service that may affect your rankings?

Comment: They said that the problems may not have been noticed by Google until they submitted my SiteMap and then the problem was picked up and my site dropped. I still don't understand why the front page disappeared, but I guess I'll figure out the meta tags and see what happens. Hopefully I'll figure it out soon.

Comment: And how long ago did they do this for you?

Comment: I signed up with them less than a week ago and the page dropped a couple of days later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure that your front page is well optimized to the keyword that you are trying to rank for and that the other page that is currently ranking is not as optimized. You may be mentioning more about the shirts on that subpage.

One the landing page, make sure that your keyword is in your title, your h1 tags, your image's alt tags (a few, not all of them) and in your meta-keywords and description. Also, you can use the SEO Quake plugin to check your keyword density. You want a density of 2-3% for that phrase.

YOu meta-tags are in the head section of your website. If your website is static, look in the code for the head. If you are using Wordpress, you can get a plugin that helps you correct this, such as SEO Ultimate.

Comment: You never want to de-optimize a page if it's naturally ranking well. Having another page that is well-optimized won't hurt your primary page. You'll just have 2 high ranking pages for a search term rather than 1 (and also keep another competing site off the SERP). With your advice, he could lose ranking on the one page that is even showing up in the index right now.